# Finding the values of a that will cause the population to become extinct

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Given the finite difference equation $x_{n+1}=ax_{n}exp(−x_{n})$ for $x_{n}≥0$, where a is a positive constant, describing the population of a species. I've determined the fixed points to be $x^∗=ln(a),0$. How do I go about determining the values of a that will cause the population to become extinct starting from any initial condition?

Comment: consider the function $f(x)=ax\mathbb e^{-x}$ for $x\ge 0$. prove that, your sequence is monotone and bounded.

Comment: How would that give me the values of a?